# How to derive $f_{X^2 Y, X Y}(m,n)$? Both $X, Y$ are exponential variables with parameter 1.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose both x and y are the exponential distribution with parameter 1. The pdf of x and y are both given as $ f_X(x)=e^{-x}, x\geq 0$.

The question is how to derive $f_{X^2 Y, X Y}(m,n)$?

The derivation of mine is as follows,

$f_{X^2 Y, X Y}(m,n)=f_{X^2 Y|X Y}(m|n)* f_{X Y}(n)$. Then set $z=x y$, the original question can be transformed into the following form, $f_{X^2 Y, X Y}(m,n)=f_{X Z|Z}(m|t)* f_{Z}(t)$. It is easy to know that $f_Z(t)=2 K_0(2 \sqrt{t}), t\geq 0$ and $f_{X| Z}(t)=\frac{e^{-\frac{t}{z}}}{z} , x\geq 0$. Hence, the problem is solved.

However, I think the above derivation is not right with the fact that $X$ and $Z=X Y$ are correlated variables. So the question is how to obtain the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M=X^2Y, N=XY$ so $X=M/N, Y=N^2/M$

Verify that these are bijective maps, $[0;\infty)^2\mapsto\hspace{-2ex}\to[0;\infty)^2$.

Use the Jacobian transformation:

$$\begin{align}f_{M,N}(m,n) ~&=~ \begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial(m/n, n^2/m)}{\partial(m,n)}\end{Vmatrix}f_{X,Y}(m/n, n^2/m) \\[1ex] &=~ \begin{Vmatrix}1/n & -m/n^2\\ - n^2/m^2&2n/m\end{Vmatrix} e^{-(m/n+n^2/m)}\mathbf 1_{m/n>0, n^2/m>0}\\[1ex] &=~ m^{-1} e^{-(m^2+n^3)/mn}\mathbf 1_{m>0, n>0}\end{align}$$